# How to apply same JQuery code to all Rails collection items

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to apply Javascript enabled rating to each of the responses to a post. Upon clicking a link, some elements are hidden and others are shown, and ratings are updated via Ajax. I added the partial count to IDs of HTML elements of each response so each of them have distinct IDs. But now how can I identify which link of which response has been clicked so that the JQuery code can process the elements associated to the relevant response? Is there a way to send IDs of links when they are clicked?

EDIT

### The Toggle Function

```
(function($) {
           return $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
           var funcs;
           funcs = [func1, func2];
           this.data("toggleclicked", 0);
           this.click(function() {
            var data, tc;
            data = $(this).data();
            tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            return data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
   });
   return this;
   };
   })(jQuery);
```

### Usage

```
$('#link1').clickToggle(function() {
    $('#link2').hide();
    $('link3').hide();
    $('#link4').show();
    $('link5').show();
}, function() {
    $('#link2').show();
    $('link3').show();
    $('#link4').hide();
    $('link5').hide();     
}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting `$(event.target)` in your `click` handler?

Comment: For Newer jQuery (1.7.2+) You will want to look at [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  For older jQuery, look at [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Simply for the benifit of making event bindings add to dynamic content.  For the end of your question, try looking at [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), but also check out [this plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) which will make it easy to ajax anything with super efficient control.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, let me try them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TT3Yn/).

Using jQuery's `on()` method I'm listening for a click event on all anchor tags. In the click handler I'm grabbing the target and pulling its ID property.

```
<a href="#" id="A">Test 1</a><br>
<a href="#" id="B">Test 2</a>​

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(event.target).prop('id'));
    });        
});​
```

Comment: Jason, the fiddle is not working for me. But I guess the suggestion is worth pursuing.

Comment: @Humming It's working for me in Chrome and IE. What's not working?

Comment: Jason, some issue with Chrome apparently. Perhaps a pop-up blocker. But worked in FireFox and it's cool. Will see if this resolves my issue, before I mark your answer. Wish I could vote up, but not enough reputation.

Comment: @Humming It looks like you have enough reputation to vote up to me. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes Jason, I did tried, but it did not worked. But strangely it worked when I tried again just now. I have the same reputation, but it appears I earned a new badge just now.

Comment: Is there a way to use the .on() method with toggle rather than a simple click? I actually have user-defined toggle function that I have to use.

Comment: @Humming It depends on what triggers the toggle. If you show the toggle function and how it gets triggered that would help.

Comment: Jason, it's a very long code, I have extracted relevant parts and generalized it for convenience.

Comment: @Humming Is there a reason you have to use that `clickToggle()` function and not jQuery's built in `toggle()` function? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Yes, for some reason JQuery's `toggle()` was doing on second click what it was suppose to do on first click. Hence I had use that.